# I can't access the login panel on my offline website

Tags: admin, login

I am really new to wordpress but have been building my site offline.  Yesterday I deleted the panel that has the login option on it, without realising.  Now I can't login to edit my page.  Does anyone have a simple solution to getting it back?
Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that

1. you have a self-hosted version of WordPress - you have your own hosting account rather than a site on WordPress.com
2. you mean you deleted/removed the widget that has the log-in link that appears on the side of your website page.

All WordPress sites have the same log-in address:

http://yoursite.com/wp-admin

So just add the /wp-admin to the end of your website address and hit enter and you will be taken to the login page.

Comment: You're my new hero!  Thank you so much!  Such a simple fix, but I had no idea. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Upvoted just for the impressive guessing what the actual issue was, I wouldn't have gotten it. :)